# Selecting nearest class that isn't a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select the header text for a clicked item using jquery/javascript. I'm having an issue writing the proper selectors given the fact that the item clicked isn't a descendant of the header section. For example, if I click item3.1, I want it to return the text "Header 3".

```
<section class="mainclass">
  <section class="header">Header 1</section>
  <ul>  
    <li>item1.1</li>
    <li>item1.2</li>
    <li>item1.3</li>
  </ul>
 <section class="header">Header 2</section>
 <ul>  
   <li>item2.1</li>
   <li>item2.2</li>
   <li>item2.3</li>
 </ul>
 <section class="header">Header 3</section>
 <ul>  
   <li>item3.1</li>
   <li>item3.2</li>
   <li>item3.3</li>
 </ul>
 <section class="header">Header 4</section>
</section>
```

Current code example:

```
jQuery('body').on('click','li',function(e) {
if (jQuery(this).parent('header').length <= 0){
    alert(jQuery(this).closest('mainclass').find('header').text());
}
});
```

This code sample returns all the headers. I haven't been able to get this to work with variants of closest, parents, find, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.prev()` to get the element just before a selection. So go up to the `<ul>`, then go back one element to get the header. Also, you need a `.` to match a class.

```js
jQuery('body').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    console.log(jQuery(this).closest('ul').prev('.header').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="mainclass">
  <section class="header">Header 1</section>
  <ul>
    <li>item1.1</li>
    <li>item1.2</li>
    <li>item1.3</li>
  </ul>
  <section class="header">Header 2</section>
  <ul>
    <li>item2.1</li>
    <li>item2.2</li>
    <li>item2.3</li>
  </ul>
  <section class="header">Header 3</section>
  <ul>
    <li>item3.1</li>
    <li>item3.2</li>
    <li>item3.3</li>
  </ul>
  <section class="header">Header 4</section>
</section>
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I needed (and the missing "." was just a typo in making my actual code generic). Thank you!